# Android SQLite no such table found error

Tags: android, sqlite

I know a lot of questions with the same name exists but this time it is different, so please read this completely.

My SQLite code is as follows

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "iListen";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "MeetingDetails";
    private static final String KEY_MEETING_NAME = "MeetingName";
    private static final String KEY_CONFERENCE_DESC = "ConferenceDescription";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "MeetingTime";
    private static final String KEY_DURATION = "MeetingDuration";
    private static final String KEY_CREATE_TIME = "CreationTime";
    private static final String KEY_PRESENTER = "MeetingPresenter";
    private static final String KEY_MEETING_KEY= "MeetingId";
    private static final String KEY_MEETING_STATUS = "Flag";
    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_MEETING_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "   + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_MEETING_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_MEETING_NAME+ " TEXT," +KEY_CONFERENCE_DESC+ " TEXT,"+ KEY_TIME+ " TEXT,"+KEY_DURATION+ " TEXT,"+KEY_CREATE_TIME+" TEXT,"+
                KEY_PRESENTER+" TEXT,"+KEY_MEETING_STATUS+" INTEGER"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MEETING_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
    public long addMeeting(MeetingList meetingList){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(KEY_MEETING_KEY, meetingList.getId());
        cValues.put(KEY_MEETING_NAME, meetingList.getMeetingName());
        cValues.put(KEY_CONFERENCE_DESC,meetingList.getConferenceDesc());
        cValues.put(KEY_TIME,meetingList.getTime());
        cValues.put(KEY_DURATION, meetingList.getDuration());
        cValues.put(KEY_CREATE_TIME, meetingList.getCreateTime());
        cValues.put(KEY_PRESENTER, meetingList.getPresenter());
        cValues.put(KEY_MEETING_STATUS,meetingList.getStatus());
        long output = db.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,cValues);
        db.close();
        return output;
    }
    public MeetingList getMeeting(Integer id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
//        Cursor cr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{KEY_MEETING_KEY,KEY_MEETING_NAME, KEY_CONFERENCE_DESC,KEY_TIME,KEY_DURATION,KEY_CREATE_TIME,KEY_PRESENTER,KEY_MEETING_STATUS},KEY_MEETING_KEY+"=?",new String[]
//                {String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
        Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+KEY_MEETING_KEY+" = ?",new String[] {id.toString()});
        MeetingList list;
        if(cr.moveToFirst()) {
//            cr.moveToFirst();
            list = new MeetingList(Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(0)), cr.getString(1), cr.getString(2), cr.getString(3), cr.getString(4), cr.getString(5), cr.getString(6), Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(7)));
        }else{
            list = null;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

I tried to insert a row into the DB but it was always returning `-1` so when I looked at the logs I saw this error

```
Error inserting CreationTime=Time = 13-02-2017 9 : 13 MeetingDuration=5 MeetingId=1 Flag=-1 ConferenceDescription=Thus club meeting was going to be held yesterday MeetingTime=Time = 13-02-2017 9 : 13 MeetingName=meeting 2 MeetingPresenter=Randomuser
                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: iListen (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO iListen(CreationTime,MeetingDuration,MeetingId,Flag,ConferenceDescription,MeetingTime,MeetingName,MeetingPresenter) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

I googled this and found several posts and almost all of then suggested me to reinstall the application, so I uninstalled and installed it again and I am getting the same error. I then tried some possiblities and came to a conclusion that the `Create`` statement might be wrong and it was, I was missing some commas so I added then and again I am getting the same error.

Any Idea what is wrong with this code?

Comment: `private static final String TABLE_NAME = "MeetingDetails";` Your table name is indeed **MeetingDetails**, not **iListen**.

Comment: Is there a reason you even need a final string for the database name?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am going to use the DB a lot of times in the class so declared it as final

Comment: Sure, you use the getReadableDatabase, for example, but you dont need the `DATABASE_NAME` for that. You only need it in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
 db.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,cValues);
```

Your first param must be table name. Change to

```
 db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cValues);
```

Check the params @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: Didn't think I would make a mistake like this..It worked

Comment: @Tyson but you should have checked your logs which is clear **no such table: iListen**

Comment: I didn't guess that I would have given the wrong string, I was checking the query over and over and was convinced that there was something wrong with the create query, so didn't pay attention to what table I was writing into

Comment: I don't think @Raghunandan really needs the reputation points but it's good to "Accept" an answer when someone give a correct solution to your problem.